# Can I install on real iPhone device the file Runner.app.zip generated by Codemajic? (Flutter project built by Codemajic)

Tags: ios, flutter

I created a Flutter app in Windows machine I tested on Android phone and now I need to test this app on a real Iphone before pushing to app store.
I built this app on Codemajic and downloaded a file named `Runner.app.zip` .
Now, how to install this file on my Iphone 7? I'm new to these stuffs, your help really appreciated.

Comment: No, you need Mac. You also won't be able to submit your app to the App Store without Mac

Answer (score 0):

1. As @zabaykal you need Mac
2. It's possible to install archives on iPhone, but you need signed `.ipa` files not `.zip` build with Xcode. In the past, recording was possible trough ItunesApp, currently Xcode is needed.
3. More convenient way is to use FirebaseDistribution/AppCenter or Apple TestFlight